# lower.tri() example in R

Tags: r, matrix, subset

My brain must not be too sharp this Friday afternoon. In the example from the lower.tri() function in R http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/lower.tri.html, you can turn all lower triangular elements of a matrix into NA as follows.

```
(m2 <- matrix(1:20, 4, 5))
lower.tri(m2)
m2[lower.tri(m2)] <- NA 
m2
```

Rather than write over the existing `m2` object, how would I save the result in a new object, say `m3`?

I tried:

```
m3 <- m2[lower.tri(m2)] <- NA
m3
```

This returns `NA`

I can get the result I want by wrapping the whole thing in a function.

```
lower.tri.na <- function(m2) {
m2[lower.tri(m2)] <- NA
return(m2)
}
m3 <- lower.tri.na(m2)
m3
```

This code below worked too (but I really wanted to use the `lower.tri()` function):

```
m3 <- ifelse(row(m2) > col(m2), NA, m2)
```

Is there a better (more efficient) way?...my guess is yes. (and dumb question why doesn't this code or style of assingment work `m3 <- m2[lower.tri(m2)] <- NA`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MrFlick has the best solution.  You can always go the route of initializing your new matrix, m3 with NAs and fill-in values from m2 with the diag(m2) and upper.tri(m2) functions.  Many ways to skin the cat in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest answer is

```
m3<-m2
m3[lower.tri(m3)] <- NA
```

Or you can do

```
m3<-`[<-`(m2, lower.tri(m2), NA)
```

which looks very awkward but it works. You're basically intercepting the value that from `[]<-`what would normally replace the variable in the assignment and sending it to a new variable.\

And your strategy of `m3 <- m2[lower.tri(m2)] <- NA` doesn't work because when you do `a <- b <- c` that's the same as `a <- (b <- c)` which is the same as `a <-c; b<-c` because the assignment operator generally passes along what was on the right side of the equation. So you're just doing `m3<-NA`. There is a special operator for matrices called `[<-` that will reshape that `NA` to an appropriate size for it's dimensions based on what you supply as an index. But here, you are not using `[]` on the `m3` so you are not getting that special behavior